# PHP not receiving jquery AJAX post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know this question has been asked dozens of times but theur solutions have not helped me. I have the simplest of codes that I have used numerous times in the past but this one is not working for apparently no reason.

Here's the html

```
<form><input type="checkbox" id="b1-19"><label for="b1-19"></label></form>
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/block-inven.php',
    type: 'POST',
    date: {
        roomId: roomId,
        date: date,
        timeSlot: timeSlot
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

The three variables have been consoled and they are showing correct values.

PHP

```
echo 'hello'; //this is returned in response
if(isset($_POST['timeSlot'])){
    echo 'hello'; // this does not get executed
}
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: If that is the HTML where are the 3 variables coming from?

Comment: I'm processing the input id. Those variables do have values

Comment: No it is supposed to be date

Comment: Where is the data being passed? you need to pass data in the ajax function

Comment: I don't think it is supposed to be `date`. There is no such key that is supposed to be sent according to the documentation - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Oh wait. damn. I didn't see that even after being pointed. You should flag this as the most stupidest question on SO. Yes the one above is `data` and inside it is `date`. It's working. Thank you very much.

Comment: happens dude..chill..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax call, you mistyped "data" to "date".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to json encode the data and also set the dataType to `json`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/block-inven.php',
    type: 'POST',
    date: {json: JSON.stringify({
        roomId: roomId,
        date: date,
        timeSlot: timeSlot
    })},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

**Then from PHP:**

```
data = json_decode($_POST['json']);
var_dump(data);
```